# SharePoint 2010 List Item Permissions

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, moss

Does anyone know of a way to implement permissions within a SharePoint list so that items are only visible to the person who created it  and also their manager (and their managers and so on). So any person can see all items that are either their own or belong to a subordinate?

I'm using SharePoint Server 2010.

I have try to use a EventReceiver,while a list item added ,setting it's permission to the user's manager,but what if  user get a promotion/demotion and they get a new manager?

Comment: This question would be better asked on [Sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to modify the standard view and set the "standard" filter to Show items only when the following is true: [Created by] [is equal to] [Me] and use a second view available for the managers only without the filter.
Of course you have to make sure that your users aren't able to change the views.

I know this seems very simple but often it works in smaller environments.

Comment: I think it works in a small environment truely ,because every one mobilization of personnel bring me a lot of work if I have many sharepoint lists like this.Still, this give me some inspiration,thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can also do one thing..
make one work flow which is run under when item has been created. then on item addition 
give permission .. in that give permission to "Created By" and "current list:manager" .. it will be very easy and working too. :) ..